# How to avoid HTML characters in contact form?

Tags: adminhtml, html, contact-form

The problem is when user submit the form with special characters in the contact form (description field), in the mail it converts to HTML characters. After lot of debugging I nailed down the following file.

\vendor\magento\module-contact\view\adminhtml\email\submitted_form.html

the file contains

```
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}

{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

I tried wrapping up %comment/$data.comment field with htmlspecialchars/ htmlentities functions. but it's not working.

For example, If I entered the following word (**Hello' world"**) in the contact form, I receive as

```
Hello&#039; world&quot;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the special character's using javascript in form element.

var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
if (!valid) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

Comment: Thanks for your time, but adding restriction to the contact form; I don't think it's ideal. Because adding more constraint, they may easily quit the task. It mean we loose customers; besides the problem is in our end.

Comment: Without htmlentities(), the textarea would interpret and display the contact form
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php